# Recurring SQL Expression Parsing Error on Query Builder

Tags: qgis, shapefile, sql, query

I am using Query Builder in QGIS 2.14.2-Essen to select one country (Peru) among 237 for which to show two layers (states_provinces, boundary lines) from the Natural Earth database. I am paying close attention to corresponding attribute tables. However, a recurring error message is generated: "OGR[3]: SQL Expression Parsing Error; syntax error, unexpected end of string." The screenshot of the message is below. 
[image: SQLerror_querybldr]

I have been unsuccesful at resolving this issue, despite widely searching the web.

Comment: And what is the SQL expression?

Comment: Referring to screenshot (now showing), it is "admin" = ´Peru´

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you use the right type of single quotes: `''`

If you use ``` `` ``` the parser will freak out.

Comment: I was double-clicking on the exact names among those listed in my desired field, so the single quotation marks appeared automatically. At any rate, now it is working BUT I have encountered another problem. I succesfully highlight one region. When I want to add a second region with AND, nothing happens (not even error message). The exact SQL is: "name" = 'Huancavelica' and "name" = 'Junín'

Comment: If it worked for you, please accept the answer. For your new problem, I think it could be related to the accent in `Junín`. If the problem persists, please ask a new question.

Comment: Steven Bernard (QGIS Tutorials in YouTube) helped me resolve it by suggesting I use OR instead of AND.