# SQL Expression Parsing Error

Tags: sql, error, expression

[This](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193668/recurring-sql-expression-parsing-error-on-query-builder) post couldnt help my problem. I try to find out how many countries start with a 'd' and have a 'n' in their name using the query.

When I type in this, `WHERE CNTRY_NAME LIKE 'd%n%'` I get the following Error

```
SQL Expression Parsing Error: syntax error, unexpected WHERE. Occurred around :
WHERE CNTRY_NAME LIKE 'd%n%'
^
```

Can someone tell me where the problem lies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When filtering, the `where` keyword must not be written and the query should **not** be ending with `;`

Try with:

`CNTRY_NAME LIKE 'd%n%'`

Comment: Thanks, I tried it. It worked.